# Can i use Lodge and stuck interchangeably

Tags: meaning

I saw these words are pretty similar to the examples that I read so i want to know if i can use them interchangeably and is LODGE often used by English speaking like you.

Answer (score 3):

They are interchangeable but only in the context of something stuck somewhere:

> I see the problem: you've got half a carrot **stuck/lodged** in the rotor of your washing machine.

*Stuck* has various other meanings, which *lodge* does not.  Some examples where *lodge* would not work:

> I'm **stuck** on this math problem.
>
> The gum is **stuck** to the bottom of my desk.

*Lodge* is also a somewhat more "educated" vocabulary word, so it may not sound appropriate in every context.